# Symfony2 include js files via loop from assetic.yml

Tags: symfony, assetic, symfony-2.3

**assets.yml:**

```
assetic:
    assets:
        base_js:
            inputs:
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/public/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/public/bootstrap3/js/bootstrap.min.js'
            output: 'js/scripts.js'
        base_css:
            inputs:
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/public/bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.min.css'
            output: 'js/styles.css'
```

**config.yml**

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: assets.yml }

#...

assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [MyAdminBundle]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
```

And in template:

```
{% block javascripts %}
   {% javascripts '@base_js' %}
       <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
   {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

However as output I get **js/80e3acc_part_1.js** and this file only includes the jquery code, boostrap is missing. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: prod or dev environment?

Comment: @cheesemacfly dev environment

Comment: And you don't have no error when running `php app/console assetic:dump --watch`?

Comment: By default the dev environment will be executed if you run the app/console command from the command line.
You can try to cleanup the cache and execute the command again. And make sure you run the: app/console assets:install web/  command to load all assets.

Comment: @sensi I am using the symlink option for assets:install. Since I am in dev I dont need to do assetic:dump because in dev assetic will handle this for me use_controller: true

Comment: Ah ok that make sense. Ok then I've no idea at the moment. But I know there was an similar issue some time ago. But I don't know how I fix it. Maybe broken dev cache. Was sometimes a issue. But occurs mostly with translation changes...

Comment: In your config posted here you have `use_controller: false`, is it a typo or...?

Comment: @cheesemacfly sry, its the prod config, not dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sadly the output filename configuration of an asset collection is currently not being used by default if none is specified within the `{% image %}`,`{% stylesheets %}` or `{% javascripts %}` tag if only one `@`-resource is present - this explains the filename **js/80e3acc_part_1.js**.

Further the `asset()` function does not work with the `@` - syntax.

use the following to fix the filename issue.

```
{% javascripts '@base_js' output='js/scripts.js' %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

or just include the output filename directly with the `asset()` function.

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/scripts.js') }}"></script>
```

This syntax is cleaner but leaves the downside of in case having to change the filename in configuration and the template if you want to rename the output file.

Please note that assetic in most cases does not automatically update the resources for cached collections if resources are added. Therefore always clear your cache using `app/console cache:clear` prior to dumping your assets.

That would explain why bootstrap was missing in the output file after dumping if you added it as second resource but did not clear the cache before using the `assetic:dump` command.

Comment: Your last point was just a typo on SO. I am in dev and assetic is set to use_controller: true so I do not need to dump the assets. I have followed your first suggestion, however I have still the same problem.

Comment: so did you 1) clear your cache 2) dump the assets afterwards 3) use one of my proposed solutions (if yes which one) ?

Comment: i suggest you have two unwated behaviors here ... the output filenam being `80e3acc` ( with `_part_1` added because you're using the debug option in dev environment ) instead of `js/script.js` ... and the missing second file ( the bootstrap.min.js ) inside the dumped output file. Could you please verify my second solution approach using the `asset()` function isn't working aswell? is the bootstrap file still missing in the dumped output with a cleaned cache?